# Why ion-tab not working in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-tabs

I am new to ionic. I am trying to play around with ion-tabs. Following is my code :-

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
 $stateProvider
    .state('abc', {
      url: "/abc",
      abstract: false,
      templateUrl: "abc.html"
    })
 .state('def', {
      url: "/def",
      abstract: false,
      templateUrl: "def.html"
    })
 .state('main', {
      url: "/main",
      abstract: false,
      templateUrl: "main.html"
    });
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
  var $state = $injector.get("$state");
  $state.go("main");
   });
});
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
 
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="def.html">
  <ion-view>
   <ul class="list">
    <h1><a class="item">abc</a></h1>
    <h2><a class="item">def</a></h2>
   </ul>
  </ion-view>
 </script>
 
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
  <ion-view>
   <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-balanced">    
    <ion-tab title="Dashboard" icon="ion-home" href="#/abc">
      <ion-nav-view name="dash-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    
    <ion-tab title="Public" icon="ion-earth" href="#/def">
      <ion-nav-view name="public-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    
    <ion-tab title="Secret" icon="ion-nuclear" href="#/abc">
      <ion-nav-view name="admin-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
   
    </ion-tabs>
  </ion-view>
 </script>
 
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="abc.html">
  <ion-view>
   <ion-content class="padding">
    <h1> Sub header example 1</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 2</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 3</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 4</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 5</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 6</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 7</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 8</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 9</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 10</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 11</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 12</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 13</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 14</h1>
    <h1> Sub header example 15</h1>
   </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
 </script>
  
    <ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
   <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
     <button class="button button-icon ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
     <button class="button button-icon ion-search"></button>
     <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-email"></button>
     <button class="button button-icon ion-ios-person"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <h1 class="title"> Main Nav bar</h1>
   </ion-nav-bar>
   <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-balanced bar-subheader">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left"></button>
    <button class="button">ABC</button>
    <h2 class="title">Sub Header</h2>
   </ion-header-bar>
   <ion-footer-bar class="bar bar-footer bar-positive">
    Footer
   </ion-footer-bar>
   <ion-nav-view>
   </ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
   <ul class="list">
    <a class="item" href="#/abc">first</a>
    <a class="item" href="#/def">second</a>
   </ul>
  </ion-side-menu>
 </ion-side-menus>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am expecting tabs to be rendered in the UI, but the problem is that, tab bar and tabs are not appearing at all.

I don't know, where I am missing. 
Apologizing for bad english. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I Think You are Forgetting to Add  and Because of that the header is not being able to be rendered in the app.
P.S Don't Use HTML Tags in IONIC. Use IONIC Specific Code.

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
   <button ion-button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Page Two</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Problem is not about header, problem is about tabs not appearing.